# Shell script to find common values and write in particular pattern with subtraction math to range pattern

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, awk, cut

Shell script to find common values and write in particular pattern with subtraction math to range pattern

Shell script to get command values in two files and write i a pattern to new file AND also have the first value of the range pattern to be subtracted by 1

```
$ cat file1
2
3
4
6
7
8
10
12
13
16
20
21
22
23
27
30

$ cat file2
2
3
4
8
10
12
13
16
20
21
22
23
27
```

Script that works:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{x[$1]=1} NR!=FNR && x[$1]' file1 file2 | sort | awk 'NR==1 {s=l=$1; next} $1!=l+1 {if(l == s) print l; else print s ":" l; s=$1} {l=$1} END {if(l == s) print l; else print s ":" l; s=$1}'
```

Script out:

```
2:4
8
10
12:13
16
20:23
27
```

`Desired output:`

```
1:4
8
10
11:13
16
19:23
27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{x[$1]=1} NR!=FNR && x[$1]' file1 file2 |
    sort |
    awk 'NR==1 {s=l=$1; next}
        $1!=l+1 {if(l == s) print l; else print s -1  ":" l; s=$1}
        {l=$1}
        END {if(l == s) print l; else print s -1 ":" l; s=$1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to sputnick's, except using `comm` to find the intersection of the file contents.

```
comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | 
sort -n |
awk '
    function print_range() {
        if (start != prev) 
            printf "%d:", start-1
        print prev
    }
    FNR==1 {start=prev=$1; next} 
    $1 > prev+1 {print_range(); start=$1}
    {prev=$1}
    END {print_range()}
'
```

```
1:4
8
10
11:13
16
19:23
27
```